# Change value of a dropdown after loading values

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I need to set a `dropdown` value after loading all the values in it. The first `dropdown` (District) value loads the values for the second `dropdown` (Councils), and `JSon` call brings the `ID` to select the value in the Councils `dropdown`, but it can only be set after is fully loaded:

```
$("#PostalCode").keyup(function () {
    loadPTPostalCode();
});

$("#PostalCodeExtension").keyup(function () {
    loadPTPostalCode();
});

function loadPTPostalCode()
{
    if ($("#PostalCode").val() >= 1000) {
       $.ajax({
            url: '/Address/GetPTPostalCode',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { postalCode: $("#PostalCode").val(), postalCodeExtension: $("#PostalCodeExtension").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                 //Set the Distict value and fire the load of the Councils Dropdown
                $("#districtDropdown").val(data.PTCouncil.PTDistrict.Id).change(function () {
                 // I tried to define the Council value after the load of his dropdown changes but no luck
                    $("#councilDropdown").val(data.PTCouncil.Id);
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert(textStatus)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I also have a cascade associated with the District Dropdown:

```
$("#districtDropdown").cascade({
    url: "/Address/ListCouncilByDistrict",
    paramName: "districtId",
    firstOption: 'Selecione o Concelho...',
    childSelect: $("#councilDropdown")
});
```

Comment: what triggers the AJAX? Code shown seems a bit unorthodox. Is it intended to create the `option` tags for second `select` ?

Comment: Hi, I had the code for the Councils Dropdown Load

Comment: If you are using a `cascade` plugin you are not explaining the problem very well. Why are you adding a new `change` handler within the AJAX shown? Please explain workflow better and provide link to docs for `cascade` plugin. Code that doesn't work is not a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: Hi, there are diferent workflows, the first is when someone choose a District from the District Dropdown, and it Cascade's and load the CouncilDropdown using the $("#districtDropdown").cascade function. The second workflow is when someone fills a $("#PostalCode").val() >= 1000 and then it selects the District, get all the associated Councils, and select the Council associated based on the JSON value in data.PTCouncil.Id. Hope this explain better the problem.

Comment: probably need to store the data and use a callback in `cascade` plugin to set value. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net. plugin docs link would help also

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand your question, but try this:

```
 success: function (data) {
                 //Set the Distict value and fire the load of the Councils Dropdown
                $("#districtDropdown").val(data.PTCouncil.PTDistrict.Id).change(function () {
                 // I tried to define the Council value after the load of his dropdown changes but no luck
                    $("#councilDropdown").val(data.PTCouncil.Id);
                }).change();
            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be an endless loop on the .change?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the Council value is not set after the Councils Dropdown is loaded :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value in council drop-down only after its gets loaded which is probably happen via another Ajax call. I am assuming that you have another java-script code that is loading the council values on change of district value (in probably district dropdown's change handler). So you need to set the council value in that function. The outline would be something like

```
success: function (data) {
  //Set the Distict value
  $("#districtDropdown").val(data.PTCouncil.PTDistrict.Id);
  // store the council id in temp storage (currently using DOM element)
  $("#councilDropdown")[0]["temp_council_id"] = data.PTCouncil.Id;
  // fire loading of council drop-down
  $("#districtDropdown").change(); // this is assuming that change handler has the
                                   // relevant code. If not then invoke that code.
}
```

Now, in the code that loads council drop-down, add code to set council id from temp storage

```
$("#districtDropdown").change(function() {
   // code to load council drop-down
   ....

   // set the selected council id (if any)
   var councilId = $("#councilDropdown")[0]["temp_council_id"];
   if (councilId) {
       $("#councilDropdown").val(councilId);
       $("#councilDropdown")[0]["temp_council_id"] = null; // clear temp storage
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I call your "// set the selected council id (if any)" code in my cascade function?

Comment: @Patrick, that's exactly what I am saying - invoke that piece of code in the code that loads your council drop-down?  If its not clear, then will advise to edit the question to include code that populated council dropdown on change in district drop-down.

Comment: Hi, the code that populate the Council Dropdown is already in the question, it's the "$("#districtDropdown").cascade" function. Th issue here is how do you wait the load of the Council dropdown, and only after that, you define his value based on your temp field?